# JSF long running processes

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

If a backing bean function takes sometime to process the request, how do we pull the progress ?

Comment: They keywords you need are "push" or "pull". Now, please refine your question.

Comment: You haven't done *any* research based on the keywords? That's not how it works here.

Comment: I tried. I don't want a progress bar. When I start the function I change a backing bean property value and when it finished , again changed the property value to something else. I bind that property to the UI. Even it only worked for the first request. I don not put questions without looking anything. I tried 2 days.

Comment: Someone helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401563/jsf-icefaces-hcommondbutton-oncomplete/15402086?noredirect=1#15402086

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer something like a progress bar. You can use a framework like Primefaces for that:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/progressBar.xhtml

Comment: I'm using Icefaces. The sample they have given is weird, not like Primefaces.